# Cannot create a node in Alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco

I tried to create a node with Alfresco using Java:

```
 AuthenticationUtil.setRunAsUserSystem();
 fileFolderService.create(repository.getCompanyHome(),"newNode",QName.createQName("cm:folder"));
```

Previously I injected fileFolderService and it is ok. I have this exception:

```
An exception occurred: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Also in the same code I cannot find already existing node with injected nodeService:

```
nodeService.getChildByName(parentNode, assocType, "myNode");
```

Has anyone some idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Well there is an IllegalArgumentException... you should be a bit more verbose, i.e. give us at least the topmost 20 or so elements of the stack trace!

Comment: You should use `ContentModel.TYPE_FOLDER` to get the QName for a cm:folder

Comment: When i use ContentModel.TYPE_FOLDER to get QName for cm:folder it works properly. Thank you very much Gyro.